# Send mail from models in CodeIgniter?

Tags: email, codeigniter, model, send

Is there a way I can use my phpmailer library to send mails from a Model?
I was wondering because I'm building a remote service which only has access to the models.

Comment: The problem was that I had to load the plugin. But as you suggested I included the mailer and it worked. Thanks

Comment: I've added it as an answer as it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Is your phpmailer library coded for Codeigniter? If not then Codeigniter is such a loose framework you can include  the mailer and just act on it's functions.